# The written SQL query doesn't display the expected output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written below query to show Output as below(bottom of page) but this is not as expected.

**Note**: Code and description are always fixed in Table A(in future more code is added), the only percentage varies, data is fetched by uniquecode and some uniquecode doesn't have the percentage and some have.

below query is not fulfilled my requirement, when Code doesn't have any percentage value then also it Code, the description should be shown and percentage column shows as NULL for that code.

```
SELECT a.Code,
       a.Description ,
       b.Percentage,
FROM TableA a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.Code = b.Code
WHERE a.Code IN('CIC', 'CIA', 'DAC', 'PIB', 'UTI', 'DAB')
     AND (b.UniqueCode = 'A100');
```

Please refer below tables,

```
Table A
---------------------------
Code    Description 
---------------------------
CIC     AAAABBBCC
CIA     HHHHAAAAA
DAC     HHHIIIIIH
PIB     BBEEERERE
UTI     GGGGGGGGGG
DAC     CCSASASAAS
BVB     HHHAAAAAAA
BBC     KKKIIIIWWW
ABC     BBMMMMAMAA

Table B:
--------------------------------
Code    Percentage  UniqueCode
--------------------------------
CIC                   A100
CIA       80          A100
DAC                   A100
PIB       100         A100
UTI       100         A100
DAB       70          A100
CIC       100         A101
CIA       80          A101
DAC                   A101
PIB       100         A101
UTI       100         A101
DAB                   A101
```

The output which is expected

```
    --------------------------------
    Code    Description  Percentage
    --------------------------------
    CIC     AAAABBBCC     NULL
    CIA     HHHHAAAAA     80
    DAC     HHHIIIIIH     NULL
    PIB     BBEEERERE     100
    UTI     GGGGGGGGG     100
    DAB     CCSASASAA     100
```

Comment: What is s.Code here, I think it may be typo of b.code.

Comment: it is a column name

Comment: The column is in which table? A or B, if it is in A table then a.code or it should be  b.code

Comment: Which table is UniqueCode in?

Comment: Table B have unique code

Comment: Can you please post your output?

Comment: this query is missing group by

Comment: @Gokul, Can you please explain why group by is needed here?

Answer (score 0):

You have included a filter on table b in your where clause, which effectively forces an inner join.   Moving it to the join condition should fix your issue.

```
SELECT a.Code,
       a.Description ,
       b.Percentage,
FROM TableA a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.Code = b.Code AND (b.UniqueCode = 'A100')
WHERE a.Code IN('CIC', 'CIA', 'DAC', 'PIB', 'UTI', 'DAB');
```